# MonoTouch: Hide UIBarButtonItem

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, hide, uibarbuttonitem

How do I hide a `UIBarButtonItem` ?

I tried google it, but didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to convert the, Objective-C, answer from: [Hide UIToolbar UIBarButtonItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971483/hide-uitoolbar-uibarbuttonitems)
into C# and do the same thing using MonoTouch.

Comment: Perfect - it worked fine. Would be nice with a UIBarButton.Hidden method, but this will do. Thanks poupou for once again helping me out here!